# Downloading layers as shapefile from ArcGIS Online maps?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api, map-service

I would like to download some features [in this website](https://apps.sfwmd.gov/WAB/EnvironmentalMonitoring/index.html). Now I can download ".lyr" file through clicking the apostrophe in the "layer list" (e.g., [here](https://sfwmd.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1a3188233736444b9ea7b11e4a37272e)). However, the ".lyr" file cannot be exported as shapefile. There is even no such a botton (see the picture below). As a result, I cannot edit it.
[image: Fig.2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is published as an image service, similar to WMS specification, and is not mainly intended to use as a download service (a service similar to WFS, would serve this intend better).

But there is a workaround, at least in this case: you can ask the service to generate the result in JSON format with geometries, and then convert the result to SHAPEFILE, if you wish.

---

Example for Watersheds layer:

1. Get the JSON result of all the geometries in the Watersheds layer (id: 5) using the URL  https://mapsprod.sfwmd.gov/map_ssl/rest/services/AHED/AHED_Drainage_Areas/MapServer/5/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&f=pjson
2. Use a GIS software or an online service as [Ogre](http://ogre.adc4gis.com/) to convert the JSON to Shapefile.

---

If you need to check further information on the service, as the layer list, the available capabilities or output formats, you can use the URL https://mapsprod.sfwmd.gov/map_ssl/rest/services/AHED/AHED_Drainage_Areas/MapServer?f=pjson

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to export data from these layers because they are map services and do not support exporting out into shp or gdb.